# React how to load code after build from database "string"

Tags: javascript, reactjs, database, webpack, dynamic

I want to load code like

```
<Button color="primary" onClick={() => changeState(data)} > something </Button>
```

where I want code that render something without having in it in code base

after building the code in production

Comment: Please explain more about the scenario

Comment: I making games website where I want the games to loaded in database as code and called when the game is clicked on react, without have to make new component to react for every game, and they will have sudo-api function to call for changing state inside that page and they will react that state